# .htaccess not working properly on subdomain with url routing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have this .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^pdf/([^/]+)/?$ pdf.php?file=$1&post=1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^pdf/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ pdf.php?file=$1&id=$2 [QSA]  

RewriteRule ^file/([^/]+)?$ file.php?file=$1 [QSA]  
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ file.php?file=$1&find=$2 [QSA]  
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ file.php?file=$1&type=$2&find=$3 [QSA]  

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/graphs/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?route=$1/graphs&view=$2 [QSA]  

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1\.php [T=application/x-httpd-php,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

this works perfect on **sub.domain.com**

but when i copied the whole thing over to **new.sub.domain.com** actual files that are being called like images are now being redirected,

so if `images/image.png` is called its sent to `index.php?route=images/image.png` not to the intended image. and it does exits in the location requested.

can anyone explain why or where i have done wrong somewhere.

i thought that this bit sorted out the real files from the redirected ones

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

or does this change when on a sub.sub.domains

locations for the sites are

```
[works] /subdomains/sub/htdocs/
[doesn't work] /subdomains/sub.sub/htdocs/
```

apache runs all sub domains from the `/subdomains/` folder from server root.

Comment: `files that are being called like images are now being redirected` what do you mean by this? How are they being directed?Also do sub and sub sub share the same document root?

Comment: i have amended the question to include what u asked.